# Am I able to query for customer_id in the Speech to Text service?

Tags: ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, speech-to-text

I have searched through the documentation and Stack Overflow but can't find information related to obtaining data on items we send to the Speech to Text service using the custom header "X-Watson-Metadata: customer_id=my_customer_ID".

Are we able to query for items such as how many minutes per time period "customer_ID" used?

Are there other items available to query for this Speech to Text service?

Answer (score 1):

The **customer_id** in IBM Speech to Text service is used to [delete data associated with that ID](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/speech-to-text?topic=speech-to-text-information-security). This can be done using th API function [user_data](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/speech-to-text#delete-labeled-data) with a DELETE request.

Comment: So they only allow us to tag the data for deletion purposes and do not allow us to query for any statistics for billing or other purposes?

Comment: I don't know if there is more available on large enterprise deployments. You may join the Watson developer Slack at wdc-slack-inviter.mybluemix.net/ and ask there. But that is all I know and what I have seen documented.